# Mysql Left join for days that do not have any data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

Good Day,
I am trying to create a SQL statement to return Status data for the last 14 days for all 4 users. I have created a Calendar table for the purpose of performing a LEFT JOIN.
given the BackupData Table:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------------
--+
| customer | Category    | user       | status    | Date                
|
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| acme     | Workstation | Judi       | [Success] | 2017-10-18 10:29:08 |
| acme     | Server      | Quickbooks | [Success] | 2017-10-18 11:25:33 |
| acme     | Server      | Quickbooks | [Success] | 2017-10-18 11:33:56 |
| acme     | Workstation | Reception  | [Success] | 2017-10-18 12:14:49 |
| acme     | Workstation | Megan      | [Success] | 2017-10-18 16:10:24 |
| acme     | Workstation | Judi       | [Success] | 2017-10-18 16:11:03 |
| acme     | Workstation | Reception  | [Success] | 2017-10-19 08:04:15 |
| acme     | Server      | Quickbooks | [Success] | 2017-10-19 11:35:47 |
| acme     | Workstation | Judi       | [Success] | 2017-10-19 16:10:13 |
| acme     | Workstation | Reception  | [Success] | 2017-10-20 08:35:26 |
| acme     | Server      | Quickbooks | [Success] | 2017-10-20 13:28:08 |
| acme     | Workstation | Judi       | [Success] | 2017-10-20 16:09:00 |
| acme     | Server      | Quickbooks | [Success] | 2017-10-21 11:33:28 |
| acme     | Workstation | Judi       | [Success] | 2017-10-21 16:11:01 |
| acme     | Server      | Quickbooks | [Success] | 2017-10-22 11:33:16 |
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I want to present the data like this:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| dt         | User       | Status    |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2017-10-18 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-18 | Megan      | [Success] |
| 2017-10-18 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-18 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Megan      | No Data   |
| 2017-10-20 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Megan      | No Data   |
| 2017-10-21 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-21 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-21 | Megan      | No Data   |
| 2017-10-21 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-22 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-22 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-22 | Megan      | No Data   |
| 2017-10-22 | Reception  | No Data   |
| 2017-10-23 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-23 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-23 | Quickbooks | No Data   |
| 2017-10-23 | Megan      | No Data   |
```

Days with no data must be displayed as "NO DATA" for a user.
My current query is eliminating null values where certain users have no Status data for a specific day as the other users may have data for that day:

```
SELECT calendar_table.dt,BackupDetail.User, BackupDetail.Status
FROM calendar_table
LEFT JOIN BackupDetail ON (calendar_table.dt = 
DATE(BackupDetail.Date))
where calendar_table.dt BETWEEN date_add(curdate(), interval -14 day) 
AND curdate()
GROUP BY calendar_table.dt,BackupDetail.User
```

Results in:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| dt         | User       | Status    |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2017-10-18 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-18 | Megan      | [Success] |
| 2017-10-18 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-18 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-21 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-21 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-22 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-22 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-23 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-23 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-24 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-24 | Megan      | [Failed]  |
| 2017-10-24 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-25 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-25 | Megan      | [Success] |
| 2017-10-25 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-25 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-26 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-26 | Megan      | [Success] |
| 2017-10-26 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-26 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-27 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-27 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-27 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-28 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-28 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-29 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-29 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-30 | Judi       | [Success] |
| 2017-10-30 | Megan      | [Success] |
| 2017-10-30 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-30 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-10-31 | Megan      | [Success] |
| 2017-10-31 | Reception  | [Success] |
| 2017-11-01 | NULL       | NULL      |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

If I change the query to query a specific user in the JOIN:

```
SELECT calendar_table.dt,BackupDetail.User, BackupDetail.Status
FROM calendar_table 
LEFT JOIN BackupDetail ON (calendar_table.dt = 
DATE(BackupDetail.Date) and BackupDetail.User = 'Quickbooks')

where calendar_table.dt BETWEEN date_add(curdate(), interval -14 day) 
AND curdate()

GROUP BY calendar_table.dt,BackupDetail.User
```

I get closer to the desired result:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| dt         | User       | Status    |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 2017-10-18 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-19 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-20 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-21 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-22 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-23 | NULL       | NULL      |
| 2017-10-24 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-25 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-26 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-27 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-28 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-29 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-30 | Quickbooks | [Success] |
| 2017-10-31 | NULL       | NULL      |
| 2017-11-01 | NULL       | NULL      |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

If you compare the result with the first table you can see the the entry for the 23rd and 31st was eliminated from the results as it was null.

Other that creating a procedure or union statement. What would be the most elegant solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Handling missing dates in application code. And NEVER include a GROUP BY clause in a query absent any aggregating functions. It’s a sure way to return nonsensical result sets.

Comment: well I can add a count , same result...

Comment: Yes. Still nonsensical!

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm only expecting 1 result per user per day...

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: There *is* (at most) only one result per user per day

Comment: So you want the result for one particular user as shown in your second result? Only that you want "NO DATA"  instead of null?

Comment: Do `Date` and `User` uniquely identify a record in `BackupDetail` or can there be multiple entries per user and date?

Comment: Still not clear - if you have only one result per user per day - then why do you put a GROUP BY clause in the first place? Remove it, replace it with ORDER BY and you'll have all running fine, or not?

Comment: Thorsten, There can me multiple entries per user per day, if a backup was completed more than once, I am after where no Status was received for a user for a specific day. I want to display the status of all users for a specific date range (7 days) even if the user has no status for a specific day in the range.

Comment: This will work if you do place aggregate functions into the query, as per standard GROUP BY - each of the columns must have an aggregate function as already mentioned several times - did you try? Put max(calendar_table), max(dt,BackupDetail.User), max(BackupDetail.Status) for example - this will avoid SQL cross-relating arbitrary values resulting in missing rows

Comment: ok, I have added the BackupData table to the question if it helps

Comment: I have also added the Desired result at the end, hope it makes it clear what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Did try max, doesn't show entries for days a user has no status

Comment: Do you have a user table?

Comment: Thanks everyone, Thorsten's answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get the dates first:

```
select dt 
from calendar_table 
where dt between date_add(curdate(), interval -14 day) and curdate();
```

Then the users:

```
select distinct user from backupdetail;
```

If you have a users table (as you should have) you'd select the users from that table instead of course.

Then let's get the status per day and user:

```
select user, date, group_concat(distinct status order by status) as statuses
from backupdetail
group by user, date;
```

If you are only interested in status = 'Success', you can of course make this a mere:

```
select distinct user, date, status
from backupdetail
where status = 'Success';
```

Now join: First create all combinations of dates and users (`CROSS JOIN`), then outer join the existing backupdetail records.

```
SELECT
 c.dt,
 u.user,
 COALESCE(b.status, 'NO DATA') as status
FROM
(
  select dt 
  from calendar_table 
  where dt between date_add(curdate(), interval -14 day) and curdate()
) c
CROSS JOIN (select distinct user from backupdetail) u
LEFT JOIN
(
  select distinct user, date, status
  from backupdetail
  where status = 'Success'
) b ON b.user = u.user AND date(b.date) = c.dt
ORDER BY c.dt, u.user;
```

Comment: Brilliant Thanks Thorsten.